# .MySQL throws an error in a JDBC Prepared statement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a database and a program in Java from which I want to make a record (via the GUI in JavaFX) into the database. I tried many times to execute the `insert into` query but the error continues to appear - *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?)' at line 1*. Here is the code:

```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("*The connection string is deliberetely omitted*");
    System.out.println("Connection established");
    String query  = "INSERT INTO User(Name,Username,PassWord) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement insertUser = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    insertUser.setString(1,MOLCreate.fieldUsername);
    insertUser.setString(2,MOLCreate.fieldUsername);
    insertUser.setString(3,MOLCreate.fieldPassword);
    //insertUser = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    insertUser.executeUpdate(query);
    conn.close();
```

I have substituted the parameters `?` with the corresponding values, also the database rows are the same as in the query. Where could be the problem?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: btw, it should be `execute(query)` not `executeUpdate(query)` for insert

Comment: @user404 You're wrong. `executeUpdate` is the right method, the OP is just using the wrong variant (they should use the `executeUpdate` without parameters).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, my bad :(  ! I agree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key here is the error
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?)'`

This implies that the actual query to your mysql contains `?` and not the intended strings.

The problem is in `insertUser.executeUpdate(query);`

Passing `query` as a parameter to `executeUpdate()` executes the raw query String. According to javadocs, this method should not be called for a PreparedStatement. The proper way to execute the PreparedStatement is to use

```
insertUser.executeUpdate();
```

Refer:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()

Also, your PreparedStatement needs to be closed, as they might cause a memory leakage.

Answer (score -1):

Let's try -

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("*The connection string is 
        deliberetely omitted*");

        **conn.setAutoCommit(false);**//Auto commit false
        System.out.println("Connection established");
        String query  = "INSERT INTO User(Name,Username,PassWord) VALUES(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement insertUser = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        insertUser.setString(1,MOLCreate.fieldUsername);
        insertUser.setString(2,MOLCreate.fieldUsername);
        insertUser.setString(3,MOLCreate.fieldPassword);
        //insertUser = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        int check=insertUser.executeUpdate(query);
        System.out.println("Check the data  inserted or not ::" + check);
        **conn.commit(); /**/
        conn.close();**strong text**
```

Comment: This will still produce the same error: the problem is with `insertUser.executeUpdate(query)` instead of `insertUser.executeUpdate()`